# SQL regex and field

Tags: sql, regex, joomla, joomla-k2

I want to change the query to return multiply values in `extra_fields`, how can I change the regex? Also I don't understand what `extra_fields` is - is it a field? If so why it is not called with the table prefix like `i.extra_fields`?

```
SELECT i.*,
    CASE WHEN i.modified = 0 THEN i.created ELSE i.modified END AS lastChanged,
    c.name AS categoryname,
    c.id AS categoryid,
    c.alias AS categoryalias,
    c.params AS categoryparams
FROM #__k2_items AS i
LEFT JOIN #__k2_categories AS c ON c.id = i.catid
WHERE i.published = 1
    AND i.access IN(1,1)
    AND i.trash = 0
    AND c.published = 1
    AND c.access IN(1,1)
    AND c.trash = 0
    AND (i.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        OR i.publish_up <= '2013-06-12 22:45:19'
    )
    AND (i.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        OR i.publish_down >= '2013-06-12 22:45:19'
    )
    AND extra_fields REGEXP BINARY '(.*{"id":"2","value":\["[^\"]*1[^\"]*","[^\"]*2[^\"]*","[^\"]*3[^\"]*"\]}.*)'
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the curly brackets in the regex?

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment

Answer (score 2):

The `extra_fields` is a column of the `#__k2_items` table. The table qualifier can be omitted, because it is not ambiguous in this query. The column is JSON encoded. That is a serialization format used to store information which is **not searchable by design**. Applying a RegExp may work one day, but fail another day, since there is no guarantee for `id` preceeding `value` (as in your example).

### The right way

The right way to filter this is to **ignore the `extra_fields` condition** in the SQL query an evaluate in the resultset instead. Example:

```
$rows = $db->loadObjectList('id');
foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {
    $extra_fields = json_decode($row->extra_fields);
    if ($extra_fields->id != 2) {
         unset($rows[$id]);
    }
}
```

### The short way

If you can't change the database layout (which is true for extensions you want to keep updateable), you *must* split the condition into two, because there is *no guarantee* for a certain order of the subfields. For some reason, one day `value` may occur *before* `id`. So change your query to

```
...
AND extra_fields LIKE '%"id":"2"%' 
AND extra_fields REGEXP BINARY '"value":\[("[^\"]*[123][^\"]*",?)+\]'
```

Comment: i prefer to keep the sql because there is pagination . anyhow i want to turn this  REGEXP BINARY '(.*{"id":"2","value":\["[^\"]*1[^\"]*","[^\"]*2[^\"]*","[^\"]*3[^\"]*"\]}.*)' into find one of the values and not the excact pharse

Comment: Well, then K2 was the wrong choice. As I said in my answer, serialized fields are not serachable *by design*.

Comment: Updated my answer to make `extra_fields` *kind of* searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare an intermediate table to hold the contents of  extra_fields. Each extra_fields field will be converted into a series of records. Then do a join.
Create a trigger and cronjob to keep the temp table in sync.

Another way is to write UDF in Perl that will decode the field, but AFAIK it is not indexable in mysql.

Using an external search engine is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i didnt want to change the db strucure, i gost some help and changed the regex into`AND extra_fields REGEXP BINARY '(.*{"id":"2","value":\[("[^\"]*[123][^\"]*",?)+\]}.*)'`

and i got the right resaults
Thanks